# Kivy: Error on iOS using JSON file for High Score

Tags: python, ios, json, kivy

I tried to set up a highscore tracker for an app by using a JSON file and the json storage language in Kivy.

I imported JSONstore and in my main game class I did

```
class Game(FloatLayout):
    highscorejson = JsonStore('highscore.json')
    highscore = NumericProperty(highscorejson.get('highscore')['best'])
```

and after I init the class, I have an end game function that ends the game and checks to see if the new score beats the old highscore.

```
def end_game(self):
    if self.score > self.highscore:
         self.highscorejson.put('highscore', best = self.score)
    self.highscore = self.highscorejson.get('highscore')['best']
```

This runs perfectly when I run it through Kivy, but when I run it through XCode using my iphone as a test device, it crashes when you score above the highscore and the game ends. The error message is as below.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/storage/__init__.py", line 174, in put
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/storage/jsonstore.py", line 39, in     store_sync
 IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'highscore.json'
2014-06-24 21:59:34.385 cookie[2320:60b] Application quit abnormally!
2014-06-24 21:59:34.457 cookie[2320:60b] Leaving
```

Full Error:
http://pastebin.com/Zy0DtysW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stuck on this problem too. So, finally, I was able to solve this problem. The next code helped me a lot.

```
from os.path import join

class MyApp(App):
def build(self):
    data_dir = getattr(self, 'user_data_dir')
    store = JsonStore(join(data_dir, 'storage_file.json'))
```

As I understand, `user_data_dir` stores an unique for each app and OS path, where current app's code is stored.

Comment: Hmm I've been playing around with this, but haven't been able to figure it out yet. I'm getting one error saying name 'join' isn't defined?

Comment: @FortuneFaded
`join` is part of `os.path`
so you need to import it using `from os.path import join`

Comment: thanks. I made a test app to test it out on, but still can't get it right. Could you take a look? http://pastebin.com/g4myCh4n

Comment: @FortuneFaded, check this out http://pastebin.com/AejGWLEN. I tested it on my iPad and it works, also I added some comments in code.

Comment: Works perfectly!!!! Thank you! Now I just need to hopefully do the same on my game.

Comment: does the data_dir code have to be in the build function of the App class?

Comment: @FortuneFaded, you are welcome (:
It seems, that it's the only one way. I'm new at kivy too, and for now I can't get better solution. JFYI in my app I defined `data_dir` as global variable and set it's value in build function. Try this.

Comment: sorry to come back to this, I got sidetracked and spent time on different parts of the project for a while. I defined data_dir as a global and set it's value in the build function, but I'm getting a data_dir is not defined error when putting the rest of the code outside of the build function. For some reason I think my build function get's ran late? If i post the code could you take a look?

Comment: @FortuneFaded,yes, I will try to help you.

Comment: awesome, thanks so much. I'm still very new to this, so my code is a bit of a mess. I'm trying out github so hopefully this works correctly https://github.com/NYamaguchi415/Cookie . The data_dir is defined in line 440 in the build method. I try to .get the score in line 59. Really sry it's so messy. First project

Comment: @FortuneFaded, the problem is in initialization of `cookiescorejson` property in `Game` class, because when it tries to access `data_dir`, `data_dir` is not set yet. You should use `cookiescorejson = None' as it's default value and initialize it in `__init__` function, like `self.cookiescorejson = JsonStore(join(data_dir, 'cookiehighscore.json'))

https://github.com/melnichevv/Cookie/compare/NYamaguchi415:master...patch-1?quick_pull=1

Comment: oh my gosh. Thank you so much melnichevv! I've been trying to tackle this problem for so long. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to save the file in an invalid location. Try including a full path to the file you want to write out - you can use `kivy_home_dir` to help with this.

```
from kivy import kivy_home_dir
from os.path import join
highscore = JsonStore(join(kivy_home_dir, 'highscore.json'))
```

Comment: Tried it out, but still getting the error   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/storage/jsonstore.py", line 39, in store_sync
 IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'highscore.json'
2014-06-25 23:29:35.968 cookie[3234:60b] Application quit abnormally!
2014-06-25 23:29:36.040 cookie[3234:60b] Leaving